# DuckDB: Truncate a timestamp to a 15 minute interval?

Tags: duckdb

Is there function or equivalent that will truncate a timestamp to 15 minute intervals, e.g. the logical equivalent of

```
    select date_trunc('15 minutes', timestamp)?
```

Comment: [epoch(time)](https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.2.8/sql/functions/time.html#:~:text=21-,epoch(time),-The%20number%20of)  does return The number of seconds since midnight, you can round that to a multiple of '15 minutes', and convert it back to time ?

Comment: BTW: Why did you not post the answers that you found for other DBMSs ?  It could create a nice collection of info on this matter....

Comment: @Luuk, they were the first questions that showed up in the search, and I wanted to keep this question focused on DuckDB.  It would be great to have a question that pointed to the appropriate solutions for each database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timebucket(interval, timestamp)` will do this.  This example show both timebucket and a modified Postgresql solution.

```
-- Truncate timestamps to N minute intervals. In this test, N=15.
WITH my_table(timestamp_column) as (
VALUES 
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:00:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:01:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:02:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:03:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:04:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:05:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:06:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:07:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:08:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:09:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:10:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:11:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:12:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:13:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:14:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:15:00+03:00'),
    (timestamp with time zone '2023-01-25T05:16:00+03:00')
)
SELECT
  timestamp_column,
  time_bucket(interval '15 minutes', timestamp_column) as with_bucket,
  date_trunc('hour', timestamp_column)
    + (floor(date_part('minute', timestamp_column) / 15)::int
        * interval '15 minute') AS like_postgres
FROM   my_table
ORDER BY timestamp_column;

┌──────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│     timestamp_column     │       with_bucket        │      like_postgres       │
│ timestamp with time zone │ timestamp with time zone │ timestamp with time zone │
├──────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ 2023-01-24 18:00:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:00:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:00:00-08   │
│ 2023-01-24 18:01:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:00:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:00:00-08   │
...
│ 2023-01-24 18:14:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:00:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:00:00-08   │
│ 2023-01-24 18:15:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:15:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:15:00-08   │
│ 2023-01-24 18:16:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:15:00-08   │ 2023-01-24 18:15:00-08   │
├──────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┤
│ 17 rows                                                              3 columns │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```